# document.getElementsByTagName('img') , how to only get png images?

Tags: javascript, image, dom

I am trying to only get images with the png attribute from the dom, does anyone know how to this?

Comment: I've tagged your question as Javascript, because I think it is, but please correct the tag if it is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To iterate over the images and return those with a *src* property ending in .png:

```
var images = document.images;
var pngs = [];
for (var i=0, iLen=images.length; i<iLen; i++){
  if (/\.png$/i.test(images[i].src))
    pngs.push(images[i]);
}
```

*pngs* is an array of images whose *src* ends in .png and will work in nearly every browser that ever supported scripting.

If you want something that uses querySelectorAll if available and a simple loop over images if not, then the following should suit (per lonesomeday's ansewr):

```
function getPngs() {

  if (document.querySelectorAll) {
    return document.querySelectorAll('img[src*=".png"]');
  }

  var images = document.images;
  var pngs = [];
  var re = /\.png$/i; 
  for (var i=0, iLen=images.length; i<iLen; i++){
    if (re.test(images[i].src)) {
      pngs.push(images[i]);
    }
  }
  return pngs;
}
```

You might get back a NodeList or an array, but if all you want to do is iterate over it then that's ok. Otherwise you'll need to convert the result of the qSA fork to an array, which is a couple more lines of code.

Comment: Thanks RobG, this will help to work across browsers and i tested it out, it  works very well.

Comment: @RubyGladiator Yes, it will work. It is, however, *much* slower than my version in browsers that have `querySelectorAll`, so it would be better to test to see if that version works first. It would also be better to do `if (images[i].src.substr(-4) === '.png')`, which will be faster than the regex.

Comment: @lonesomeday - dunno what your test is, but [this one](http://jsperf.com/qsavsloop) on jsperf shows looping over *document.images* to be a lot faster in every browser I tested. It is often the case that writing a little more code in a simple loop is faster then a little less code using a complex function.

Comment: `qSA` is significantly faster on that test for me in FF and Chromium.

Comment: Beware of results for QSA tests. Browsers tend to cache the results of QSA queries now.

Comment: @Matt - so in testing, the DOM should be changed to force a new lookup?

Comment: @RobG Apologies for painting with a wide brush, but the remark was directed at Opera 11.x, which now caches QSA queries. Indeed, a constantly shifting DOM is the remedy to this problem.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the performance tests, someone added a function to convert images to an array, which is completely redundant and very expensive on performance!

Answer (score 5):

There is no safe way of doing this. The browser does not expose anywhere what type of image has been loaded. Moreover, you can't even guarantee that the image URL will have the correct file extension, because `http://example.com/some/image` is a quite valid URL.

You can get an approximation using the "attribute contains" CSS selector with `querySelectorAll` with browsers that support it:

```
var pngs = document.querySelectorAll('img[src*=".png"]');
```

That finds all `img` elements with `.png` somewhere in their `src` attribute. Note that this is vulnerable both to false positives and to false negatives.

This method will not work in IE 7 or below.

Comment: It won't work in IE 8 either, though you could also itereate over the [images collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-90379117) and use a regular expression on the *src* property to do the same thing in browsers that don't have *querySelectorAll* support. It would probably be faster in general.

Comment: Well, not necessarily a regex: `String.prototype.indexOf` would work fine. You could do the iteration yourself, but it would probably be quickest and easiest to use a Javascript library designed for these purposes...

Comment: A regular expression will be better as it can eaily test if the *src* ends in .png rather than occurs anywhere in the string. It takes about five lines of code to iterate over the images collection and return an array of images that meet some criterion. And it will be faster than any library equivalent.

Comment: Ending in `.png` isn't what I was aiming for (and could be done without regex with `substr`) because `/image.png?width=200` is not unlikely as an image URL.

Comment: Then you can easily change the regular expression, or trim the searh part of the url, or use indexOf, whatever. I'm just pointing out that there are more flexible and more specific options.